# What can i do with moderator tools?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Recently i earned the privilege to see moderator tools. This is what i see in the page.
[image: se moderator tools]

#### What can i do with the tools? just see the data?

Comment: Congratulations!  I think I should be able to see those tools too.  I see other stuff and charts but don't see anything at all that looks like this screenshot, and I've clicked through the options...

Answer (score 5):

The main part of your new privilege is being able to delete and undelete questions, which does not require the Tools page. And yes, most of these tools are informational. However, knowledge confers some additional power. You can

1. get the list of questions with 4 close votes, and close them
2. get the list of questions with 2 delete votes, and delete them
3. get the list of questions/answers that were deleted recently, and maybe vote to undelete if they should not be deleted.
4. see the list new tags, and delete them if they were created by mistake, by retagging (and you are given inline tag editor for this)
5. check out the statistics on reasons for closing, and on success of migration, and use them to argue your point on meta.

But generally, the tools are not as important on a relatively young beta site as on largest sites with tons of things to moderate.